# Get the source of the request in padrino

Tags: sinatra, padrino

Is it possible to get the source of the request in padrino in a server to server communication.For example if there are two server server1 and server2 and if server1 send a request to server2, is it possible to know in server2 that the request came from server1. the application may be in sinatra or padrino.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is dedicated fields for that type of information in [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Field_names), but you can without problem specify yourself some attributes that will be checked by the target server.
You can even add them to your requests headers and [retrieve them](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinatrarb/mwAcT0RAYv0).